# Are Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh seperate or just different forms of Brahman?

Tags: vishnu, brahman

Are Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh present or these are just different forms taken by Brahman as per the action that needed to be performed?

Comment: There are three views on this (actually there are several but these are the three popular ways). Vaishnava viewpoint: Brahma and Mahesh are actually jivas, i.e. separate invidual entities. Whereas Lord Vishnu is the God or Brahman, He is the antaryami of the two. Shaivite viewpoint: Lord Brahma and Lord Vishnu are actually separate beings who were created by Lord Shiva. Lord Shiva is eternal and absolute. Advaita viewpoint: Lord Brahma, Lord VIshnu and Lord Shiva are ONE AND THE SAME BEING. They are different forms taken based on the kind of devotion exhibited by devotees. All the best.

Comment: duplicate of many different similar questions. Do a search on the site of 'Brahma Vishnu' to see.

Answer (score 2):

How are your two questions contradictory? The trinity are present and are just the different forms of Brahman.

From the standpoint of duality, i.e. from the standpoint of objective Universe, the trinity of Brahma, vishnu and Shiva are understood as representing three phenomenons/functions of manifestation, preservation and dissolution.

But, from a higher standpoint, Brahman alone exist. It is Brahman who has manifested as Brahma, as Vishnu and as Shiva.

From the absolute standpoint of Brahman, Brahman alone exist. No duality, hence no independent creation exists.

So, it all depends upon from what standpoint, are you approaching the concept of trinity.

For reference, see Taittiriya Upanishad (3.1.1), which says, "Know that as Brahman, from which the Universe has manifested, in which it exists and into which it dissolves."

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  Answers on this site should be backed up with details and sources (preferably scripture), they shouldn't just be two lines long.  So I'm deleting your answer and converting it to a comment.  If you want to expand this into a proper answer, then edit it and flag me to undelete it.

Comment: OK, I'm undeleting your answer.